# How many versions back is it common to test iOS apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, version, backwards-compatibility

Is it common to test apps for compatibility with much older iOS versions (in my case, iOS 4.3 apps with iOS 2.x)? Or are most apps just tested one version back or so. Any idea what percentage of the iOS market will be lost to me if my app doesn't work on much older versions? I'm guessing a miniscule amount, but that seems to be enough for my employer to ask me for distant backwards compatibility -_-

Comment: As currently asked, this question is subject to closure as "too localized" because it only applies to a specific point in time.  You may want to rephrase along the lines of "how many versions back is it common to test applications?"

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Changed it a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This varies quite a bit app-to-app, depending on features being used and broadness/niche-ness of market.  The broadest you should target is: current release, previous "dot" release, last version of previous major release.  (Now, with 5.0 not yet released, that would be 4.3, 4.2, 3.2 (which was iPad only, so 3.1.3 for iPhone/iPod).

My suggestion is that you never need to support more than this.  If your product doesn't work on 3.0, the user can update for free.  Of course older hardware doesn't always update, and if your market is "people getting left behind" (which usually doesn't overlap with "people spending money in the app store") you can support older.

Some will only support newer because of powerful features being used in newer releases.  4.0 had a lot of great additions (blocks/GCD/multitasking among them).  Leave 3.x behind as soon as you can.

If your audience is a push-the-edge crowd, you can just support the latest (4.3, 4.2 right now - realistically, there's not huge API differences there).

I have an app targeted at 5.0 that will not support anything older, newer APIs are central.

As far as testing, if you have the oldest hardware with the smallest RAM you think you are targeting, that will help test.  CPU and memory can really be pushed on those.

Comment: I'd generally agree with this. Marco Arment (Instapaper dev) discusses his perspective on this issue on a recent [podcast](http://5by5.tv/buildanalyze) and touches on stats in his [blog](http://www.marco.org/2011/03/24/ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper-3-0)

Comment: Thanks, this is good to hear. I am very reluctant to leave GCD and use multi-threading.